# Resetting autoincrement column in Android SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

In sqlite.

I deleted my table's row which is hour old using this query.

```
DELETE FROM detail1 WHERE date < DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hours');
```

But the unique id column "_id" doesn't look sequential in number,Please help me with some Query.

For Info: my table has three column namely

```
_id
content1
date
```

Comment: I don't think the auto-increment column can be sequential if you delete some random rows from it.

Comment: You shouldn't use an autoincrement column to provide listbox indices; they're there for _identification_ and not for _sorting_. (They're also not for ordering unless you like “original insertion order” a lot, but that's not something you should care about a lot in a DB.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a table in DB - sqlite_sequence. It contains all sequences from the database, You can reset sequence by updating seq column to 0.

But... I think it is not the issue, why would you like to have sequential _id, especially after delete?

Comment: Am listing the data from sqlite in Android dialog box.But am not able to pickup the right "_id",when the user select the particular item

Comment: I don't think it is good approach - You should make a conversion between on screen order and DB ids (ie. first record on screen maps to _id=10), especially, when deleting operation is in scope. Other option is manually refreshing _id column after each deletion eg. by using ROWID.